# GCC -mno-cygwin option destroys exe functions

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I'm trying to build c source file using MingW-Cygwin, When i use `gcc source.c -o test` the result works fine and every functions in the compiled exe file are ok but the exe need [cygwin1.dll] to work.

and when i use `gcc -mno-cygwin source.c -o test` the exe compiled able to run without dll needing but the functions for the exe file don't work (the exe stucks).

i tried all gcc version and cygwin and mingw[w64] and all the same result.

i have a previous compiled exe and it works fine without needing for dll file so i searched for the compiler and detected {MinGW(GCC: (GNU) 4.9.3 20150626 (Fedora Cygwin 4.9.3-1))[-]}.

So anyone can help me to compile the file without erros or a link to the fedora cygwin listed above because i searched a lot of and didn't find any thing.

NOTE: also i tried cross-compiling in linux and the same result the exe stucks!

Comment: "stucks" is not a word. What actually happens?

Comment: Freezing without any works

Comment: As far as I know `cygwin1.dll` contains the Posix functions Windows is missing. So check what Posix functions you are using that are in `cygwin1.dll`

Comment: I don't want to edit any thing in the source because it is able to build without edits only in MinGW(GCC: (GNU) *.*.* ******** (Fedora Cygwin *.*.*-*

Comment: Probably undefined behaviour somewhere, show some code please

Comment: while (left > 0) {
   int size = (left > BUF_SIZE ? BUF_SIZE : left);
   size = read(fdIn, buf, size);
   write(fdOut, buf, size);
   left -= size;
  }

Comment: the problem happened when [left -= size]

Comment: Please append a full compilable example to the question above (use the edit function). You at least have to handle the cases when `read()` returns <= 0 (EOF or error).

Comment: Please understand me the problem is not in the source because it is able to build in mingw fedora cygwin but i didn't find a way to download it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for each one interested but i solved the problem by merging the exe with .dll files using own method and everything is OK..